# Apply corresponding color and icon when item is selected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on the modal picker component that lets users sort the cryptocurrencies based on **Market Cap** and **Volume** key.

I have implemented the layout and onPress event, but I don't know how to apply color (`#03AE9D`) and toggle sort icons (`sort-desc` or `sort-asc`) on it properly when the item is selected.

Here is my code snippet. For the sake of simplicity, I removed the `StyleSheet` code.

The complete version could be found [here](https://github.com/ytliuSVN/crypto-app/blob/acd39a7c537c7687086e2d8addf51f0e86aee298/app/components/ModalPicker.js).

```
// app/components/ModalPicker.js

const OPTIONS = ['market cap', 'volume'];

const ModalPicker = (props) => {
  const [isSelected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const color = useMemo(() => {
    return isSelected ? '#03AE9D' : '#676767cf';
  }, [isSelected]);

  const onPressCallback = useCallback(() => {
    setSelected((prev) => !prev);
  }, [setSelected]);

  const onPressItem = (option) => {
    props.changeModalVisibility(false);
    props.setData(option);
  };

  const option = OPTIONS.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={
          index === OPTIONS.length - 1 ? styles.noBorderOption : styles.option
        }
        key={index}
        onPress={() => onPressItem(item)}
      >
        <View style={styles.sort}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, { color }]}>{item}</Text>
          {/* <FontAwesome name='sort-desc' size={24} color='#676767cf' /> */}
          {/* <FontAwesome name='sort-asc' size={24} color='#676767cf' /> */}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  });

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => props.changeModalVisibility(false)}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.modal}>
        <ScrollView>{option}</ScrollView>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
export default ModalPicker;
```

That's the whole point of the question. Any suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to fire `onPressCallback`?

Comment: Could you provide some more examples?

Comment: See here https://snack.expo.io/@yentln/jealous-candy using your code. Screencast: https://share.getcloudapp.com/rRuG2Lpx. As you can see it's applying the color style with an active index state. So the color will only apply to that item. The same thing can be done for the sort icons. `isSelected` isn't needed anymore either.

Comment: Nicely done! Thanks for your great help. [ModalPicker.js](https://github.com/ytliuSVN/crypto-app/blob/aacb4890570a4a3bfcd0869a2ebfe267c49c3eb9/app/components/ModalPicker.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue. You can add a active index state and set it in the onPress callback:

```js
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState();

const onPressItem = (option, index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    setSelected(true);
    //props.changeModalVisibility(false);
    //props.setData(option);
  };
```

Then use it in the items map:

```js
const option = OPTIONS.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={
          index === OPTIONS.length - 1 ? styles.noBorderOption : styles.option
        }
        key={index}
        onPress={() => onPressItem(item, index)}
      >
        <View style={styles.sort}>
          <Text style={activeIndex === index && isSelected ? styles.text : styles.textInactive}>{item}</Text>
          {/* <FontAwesome name='sort-desc' size={24} color='#676767cf' /> */}
          {/* <FontAwesome name='sort-asc' size={24} color='#676767cf' /> */}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  });
```

See a snack here for working example https://snack.expo.io/@yentln/jealous-candy